# Comparing if a stack of data exists in two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, var

im new to Oracle and sql but I was assigned this job and I hope someone can help me out with this one.

Basically I am given a database link to connect to a remote database and I extract some information from a single table in there and a few other tables from a local database, and then process it and insert it into a table in the local database. I`ve managed to do this succesfully but now I need a way to confirm that all of the data from the remote database was actually copied into the local database. How would I go about doing this?

This is the code I have to insert the information to my local db.

```
INSERT INTO kcrt_requests_int RI 
  RI.TRANSACTION_ID, 
  RI.DESCRIPTION, 
  RI.CREATED_USERNAME, 
  RI.REQUEST_TYPE_ID, 
  RI.STATUS_ID, 
  RI.WORKFLOW_ID, 
  RI.WORKFLOW_STEP_ID, 
  RI.RELEASED_FLAG, 
  RI.USER_DATA1, 
  RI.USER_DATA2, 
  RI.USER_DATA3, 
  RI.USER_DATA4, 
  RI.USER_DATA7)

SELECT 
  KCRT_TRANSACTIONS_S.NEXTVAL, 
  RD.PARAMETER13||' '||R.DESCRIPTION, 
  '[SYS.USERNAME]', 
  '0001', 
  '31876', 
  '34987', '1234', 
  'Y', 
  PP.PROJECT_ID,
  VP.REVIEWDATE,
  RD.PARAMETER9, 
  R.REQUEST_ID, 
  RD.PARAMETER13

FROM 
  KCRT_REQUEST_TYPES_NLS RT, 
  KCRT_REQUESTS R, 
  KCRT_REQUEST_DETAILS RD, 
  v_projects@XXXXX VP, 
  PM_PROJECTS PP


WHERE 
  R.REQUEST_TYPE=RT.REQUEST_TYPE_ID 
  AND R.REQUEST_ID=RD.REQUEST_ID 
  AND RD.BATCH_NUMBER=1 
  AND RT.REQUEST_TYPE_NAME 'AAAAA' 
  AND R.STATUS_CODE = 'BBBBB' 
  AND RD.PARAMETER13 = to_char(VP.IDBANK)   
  AND VP.REVIEWDATE=(SELECT MAX (VP.REVIEWDATE) FROM v_projects@XXXXX VP) 
  AND R.REQUEST_ID=PP.PFM_REQUEST_ID 
  AND RD.BATCH_NUMBER=1
```

So pretty much I will try to compare RI.USER_DATA7 to VP.IDBANK and see if KCRT_REQUESTS_INT has every row that v_projects@XXXXX has.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't get into the specifics of your tables because it would take more time than I have to analyze the queries, but in general you can compare two tables with these two queries: `SELECT * FROM TableA MINUS SELECT * FROM TableB` will list any rows in `TableA` that aren't in `TableB` and `SELECT * FROM TableB MINUS SELECT * FROM TableA` will list any rows in `TableB` that aren't in `TableA`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a unique identifier column which is defined as primary key.if yes,you can join both tables on Primary key  and see if the count matches with count without join on source table.

assumes ,Table A is your source and Table B is where you have loaded data. let P_key be primary key column.

You can match:

```
select count(1) 
from Table_A with 

select count (1) 
from Table_A,Table_B 
where Table_A.P_key=Table_B.P_Key
```

If they match ,you have all the records. Hope this helps.